Spring webclient - onStatus does not return mono.empty() when using toentity()
On 404 error, exception isn't ignored. Exception is thrown.
webClient.put()
         .uri(requestUrl)
         .bodyValue(request)
         .retrieve()
         .onStatus(NOT_FOUND::equals, rs -> Mono.empty())
         .toEntity(MyClass.class);
    ```
    

 

Mono.empty() is ignored instead exception is thrown. How to handle this?

